# MongoDB - remove many from arrays of all existing elements

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have some simple user data. Here is example for one user:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  userName: {
    type: String,
  },
  projectsInput: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Project",
    },
  ],
  projectsHold: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Project",
    },
  ],
});
```

[image: I want by]

I want by having ProjectId to be able to remove all records from all users that contains it.
if I get the first one

> **`60f02d21159c4b4110f21a32`**

how I can perform updateMany function for my UserModel?

```
  return UserModel.updateMany(
              {
                projectsInput: {
                  $elemMatch: args.projectId,
                },
              },
              {
                projectsInput: {
                  $slice: [projectsInput.$, 1],
                },
              }
            );
          })
```

Here is my code that is not working.
args.projectId = 60f02d21159c4b4110f21a32 (my id for the project I want to delete)

and UserModel is my mongodb Schema for user.

Answer (score 0):

you can use $pull

```
{
  $pull: {
    projectsInputs: "123"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you structure the whole query

Comment: return UserModel.updateMany(
    {
      projectsInput: {
        $elemMatch: args.projectId,
      },
    },
    {
      $pull: {
        projectsInput: args.projectId,
      },
    }
  );